How can one fix random freezing of Windows 10 in VirtualBox?
I use VirtualBox 7.0.12:

Guest OS: Windows 10 Pro
Host OS: Windows 10 Pro (64 GB RAM, 2 TB NVMe M.2 SSD)

From time to time, the guest Windows 10 Pro. The only was I found to unfreeze it is to initiate a shutdown by VirtualBox, which is an issue as I typically don't want to shut it down. How can I unfreeze it without shutting it down?
I looked at VirtualBox and the CPU isn't maxed out and I still have half of the RAM available (32 GB out of 64 GB):


I thought of two soulutions that may work.
Solution 1 - Platforms

Go to the search bar and type in 'features' and select "Turn Windows Features on or off."
Scroll down to find "Windows Hypervisor Platform". Turn it off.
Find "Virtual Machine Platform". Turn it on, (or off if it was already on.).
Click OK.
Reboot and try again.

Solution 2 - Virtual Box Stuff
After some digging on the net, I found something in the VBox 7 family.
If you have Guest Additions 7, replace it with Guest Additions 6.
If that does not work, try changing the graphics controller to VboxVGA (3D acceleration off).
Finally, if that does not work... Export your VM data and try reinstall VBox 7. (or VBox 6.1.4.)
Hopefully this helps!
